# Get the correct x and y coordinate on mouseover

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

```
<div 
v-for="day in week.days"
        :key="day.timestamp"

        @mouseover="selectDate($event,day)">
</div>

            <div v-show="displayEvents.length!=0" ref='eventList'
     style= "
     background:red; 

     height:min-content;
      width:200px; 
      position:absolute; "
      >
      {{displayEvents}}
    </div>


    <script>
     selectDate: function(event, day) {

      this.$refs.eventList.style.top = event.clientY + "px";
      this.$refs.eventList.style.left = event.clientX + "px";

    },
    </script>
```

[image]

For some reason whenever I hover on the date selected the box only displays on the top left of the page, however what I am trying to achieve is to actually display the box precisely where the cursor pointer is, so in my case will be on top of the date highlighted in green  (12th), as a normal tooltip would work.

Comment: Please remove the typo in the html code you've shared. It has unmatching closing `</div>`

Comment: Done, thanks! @vahdet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this issue by using `pageY` and `pageX` instead of `clientY` and `clientX`.

Answer (score 1):

`clientX` and `clientY` are not css-rules. You must use `left` and `top`, respectively.

Like this:

```
<div
    v-show="displayEvents.length!=0"
    ref="eventList"
    style="
        background:red; 
        height:50px;
        width:200px; 
        position:absolute;"
>
</div>

<script>
    document.addEventListener('mouseover', event => {
        this.$refs.eventList.style.top = event.clientY + "px";
        this.$refs.eventList.style.left = event.clientX + "px";
    })
</script>
```

Note that the position of the div will be relative to the first ancestor element with `position: relative`, or, if no such ancestor is found, to the body element.

**EDIT:** I see that you edited your code to use `top` and `left`. Provided your code is executed by the correct event, it should work.

Comment: Thank you for your response, I have edited my code, however I still get this issue, please have a a look at my code edited in case I have missed something out, thanks!

Comment: Do you emit the mouseover-event somewhere? It is hard to see where you're going wrong without seeing all the relevant code. Could you post a jsfiddle with all the relevant parts of your code?